# Why i can`t start Local Development Server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run App Engine locally on Google’s Python sample code by typing in   directory that contains my app's: "dev_appserver.py .", as it is explained here: [Using the Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server)
But I`am getting next error:

> $ dev_appserver.py .
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 96, in 
>       _run_file(**file**, globals())
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
>       execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 617, in 
>       main()
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 605, in main
>       dev_server.start(options)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\devappserver2.py", line 266, in start
>       env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 938, in **init**
>       config_paths = self._config_files_from_paths(config_paths)
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 1006, in _config_files_from_paths
>       self._config_files_from_dir(path) if os.path.isdir(path) else [path])
>     File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\application_configuration.py", line 1037, in _config_files_from_dir
>       (dir_path, or_web_inf))
>   google.appengine.tools.devappserver2.errors.AppConfigNotFoundError: "." is a directory but does not contain app.yaml or app.yml

There is app.yaml file in directory from whom I am calling dev_appserver.py with next content:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

Comment: Is your `app.yaml` file like that? Because the script part has to be at the same level as the url, aka, need to space it correctly. Check some examples of it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/appref)

Comment: Can you try giving it a path to the `app.yaml` file directly? E.g.: `dev_appserver.py app.yaml`

Comment: app.yaml is ok, i downloaded it directly form googol example.zip file. I also tried to give path to file directly, it didn`t work.